# Symfony 6.4 - doctrine migration for different entity manager

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony6, doctrine-migrations

I''m using below versions of symfony 6.4, doctrine bundle & doctrine-migrations-bundle:

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.11",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2.2",
    "doctrine/migrations": "^3.7",
    "doctrine/orm": "^3.0"
```

My doctrine.yaml file looks like:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    connections:
        default:
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '8.0.36'
            charset: 'UTF8'
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            logging: true
        postgres:
            driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
            server_version: '10'
            charset: 'UTF8'
            url: '%env(resolve:POSTGRES_DATABASE_URL)%'
            logging: true
    
    default_connection: postgres

    # url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    # schema_filter: ~^(?!(Currency|table2))~

    # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
    # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
    #server_version: '15'

    # profiling_collect_backtrace: '%kernel.debug%'
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            # naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
            mappings:
                Main:
                    is_bundle: false
                    # type: attribute
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                    alias: Main
        postgres:
            connection: postgres
            # naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
            mappings:
                Postgres:
                    is_bundle: false
                    # type: attribute
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Postgres'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Postgres'
                    alias: Postgres
```

my doctrine_migrations.yaml file looks like:

```
doctrine_migrations:
em: 'default'
migrations_paths:
    'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations/Main'
    'DoctrineMigrations\Postgres': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations/Postgres'

storage:
    table_storage:
        table_name: 'doctrine_migration_versions'
        version_column_name: 'version'
        executed_at_column_name: 'executed_at'
        execution_time_column_name: 'execution_time'

services: ~
```

I followed the symfony document at [here](https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). As mentioned in the document, I'm running the below commands:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --em=default
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --em=postgres
```

But it always generates the migration files into the folder"migrations/Main". I wanted to generate the migration files into the folder "migrations/Postgres" for the option --em=postgres.

I tried to use a different doctrine_migrations.yaml file for default & postgres entity manager but it didn't work as expected.

How do the migrations as per the entity manager?